# hql fetching part of collection with restriction even if they don't have any

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

So I have an Employee entity and a Punch entity. Punch has an Employee and the epoch time when it's been "created" and the employee has a list of Punch.

Employee.java

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends AbstractScheduleEntity<EmployeeSchedule> 
{
    //AbstractScheduleEntity also extends AbstractServerEntity
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @CollectionType(type = "ca.tecsar.core.sql.LazySetType")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Punch> punches;

    //Constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Punch.java

```
@Entity
public class Punch extends AbstractServerEntity {
    //AbstractServerEntity has the @Id and few others field
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Employee employee;
    private long adjustedIn = -1;

    //Constructors, getters and setters
}
```

So I'm using a HQL query to obtain all Employee with only the punches between those 2 dates (like only a part of the collection). What could I change to my query to get what I want? I don't see what I can do.

```
SELECT e 
FROM Employee e 
LEFT JOIN FETCH e.punches p 
WHERE p IS NULL OR p.adjustedIn BETWEEN :start AND :end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve my problem was to use Hibernate's filter.
In my Employee model I only had to declare my filter for my collection :

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@CollectionType(type = "ca.tecsar.core.sql.LazySetType")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Filter(
        name="punchesBetweenDates",
        condition="{p}.adjustedIn >= :start and {p}.adjustedIn < :end",
        aliases = {
                @SqlFragmentAlias(alias = "p", table = "PUNCH")
        }
)
private Set<Punch> punches;
```

and then enable it in my query :

```
session.enableFilter("punchesBetweenDates")
                .setParameter("start", start)
                .setParameter("end", end);
```

I have to use @SqlFragmentAlias because I'm using multiple filters and some of them was using the same column name.